# App compiles WITHOUT protocol functions - why?

Tags: ios, swift, protocols

Beginner with swift so please be gentle

I'm playing around with the AppDelegate.swift file in the `Master-Detail` sample provided with `XCode`. The `Appdelegate` file has the first line

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
```

Which I understand to mean that AppDelegate is a sub-class of UIResponder and conforms to the `UIApplicationDelegate` protocol

Conforming to the `UIApplicationDelegate` protocol means, as far as I understand, that it must have methods for:

```
applicationDidBecomeActive:
applicationWillResignActive:
applicationDidEnterBackground:
applicationWillEnterForeground:
applicationWillTerminate:
```

However, when I remove all of these the app still compiles. Does this mean these methods are optional? If so what's the value in having the protocol?

Comment: The value is - if you do not need these methods - you do not implement them. Yes, they are optional, read about *Optional Protocol Requirements* here https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html.

Comment: Are they more of a guide then as in 'expect these functions to be called'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All methods are optional check out the definition of `UIApplicationDelegate` protocol, you can goto the definition by <kbd>⌘</kbd> + Clicking on class name, which is `UIApplicationDelegate`

```
protocol UIApplicationDelegate : NSObjectProtocol {

    optional func applicationDidFinishLaunching(application: UIApplication)
    @availability(iOS, introduced=6.0)
    optional func application(application: UIApplication, willFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject : AnyObject]?) -> Bool
    @availability(iOS, introduced=3.0)
    optional func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject : AnyObject]?) -> Bool

    optional func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication)
    optional func applicationWillResignActive(application: UIApplication)
    optional func application(application: UIApplication, handleOpenURL url: NSURL) -> Bool // Will be deprecated at some point, please replace with application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:
    @availability(iOS, introduced=4.2)
    optional func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject?) -> Bool // no equiv. notification. return NO if the application can't open for some reason

    optional func applicationDidReceiveMemoryWarning(application: UIApplication) // try to clean up as much memory as possible. next step is to terminate app
    optional func applicationWillTerminate(application: UIApplication)
    optional func applicationSignificantTimeChange(application: UIApplication) // midnight, carrier time update, daylight savings time change

    optional func application(application: UIApplication, willChangeStatusBarOrientation newStatusBarOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientation, duration: NSTimeInterval)
    optional func application(application: UIApplication, didChangeStatusBarOrientation oldStatusBarOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientation)

    optional func application(application: UIApplication, willChangeStatusBarFrame newStatusBarFrame: CGRect) // in screen coordinates
    optional func application(application: UIApplication, didChangeStatusBarFrame oldStatusBarFrame: CGRect)

    // This callback will be made upon calling -[UIApplication registerUserNotificationSettings:]. The settings the user has granted to the application will be passed in as the second argument.
    @availability(iOS, introduced=8.0)
    optional func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterUserNotificationSettings notificationSettings: UIUserNotificationSettings)

    @availability(iOS, introduced=3.0)
    optional func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData)

    @availability(iOS, introduced=3.0)
    optional func application(application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: NSError)

    @availability(iOS, introduced=3.0)
    optional func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject])

    @availability(iOS, introduced=4.0)
    optional func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveLocalNotification notification: UILocalNotification)

    // Called when your app has been activated by the user selecting an action from a local notification.
    // A nil action identifier indicates the default action.
    // You should call the completion handler as soon as you've finished handling the action.
    @availability(iOS, introduced=8.0)
    optional func application(application: UIApplication, handleActionWithIdentifier identifier: String?, forLocalNotification notification: UILocalNotification, completionHandler: () -> Void)

    // Called when your app has been activated by the user selecting an action from a remote notification.
    // A nil action identifier indicates the default action.
    // You should call the completion handler as soon as you've finished handling the action.
    @availability(iOS, introduced=8.0)
    optional func application(application: UIApplication, handleActionWithIdentifier identifier: String?, forRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject], completionHandler: () -> Void)

    /*! This delegate method offers an opportunity for applications with the "remote-notification" background mode to fetch appropriate new data in response to an incoming remote notification. You should call the fetchCompletionHandler as soon as you're finished performing that operation, so the system can accurately estimate its power and data cost.

     This method will be invoked even if the application was launched or resumed because of the remote notification. The respective delegate methods will be invoked first. Note that this behavior is in contrast to application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:, which is not called in those cases, and which will not be invoked if this method is implemented. !*/
    @availability(iOS, introduced=7.0)
    optional func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void)

    /// Applications with the "fetch" background mode may be given opportunities to fetch updated content in the background or when it is convenient for the system. This method will be called in these situations. You should call the fetchCompletionHandler as soon as you're finished performing that operation, so the system can accurately estimate its power and data cost.
    @availability(iOS, introduced=7.0)
    optional func application(application: UIApplication, performFetchWithCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void)

    // Applications using an NSURLSession with a background configuration may be launched or resumed in the background in order to handle the
    // completion of tasks in that session, or to handle authentication. This method will be called with the identifier of the session needing
    // attention. Once a session has been created from a configuration object with that identifier, the session's delegate will begin receiving
    // callbacks. If such a session has already been created (if the app is being resumed, for instance), then the delegate will start receiving
    // callbacks without any action by the application. You should call the completionHandler as soon as you're finished handling the callbacks.
    @availability(iOS, introduced=7.0)
    optional func application(application: UIApplication, handleEventsForBackgroundURLSession identifier: String, completionHandler: () -> Void)

    @availability(iOS, introduced=8.2)
    optional func application(application: UIApplication, handleWatchKitExtensionRequest userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]?, reply: (([NSObject : AnyObject]!) -> Void)!)

    @availability(iOS, introduced=4.0)
    optional func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication)
    @availability(iOS, introduced=4.0)
    optional func applicationWillEnterForeground(application: UIApplication)

    @availability(iOS, introduced=4.0)
    optional func applicationProtectedDataWillBecomeUnavailable(application: UIApplication)
    @availability(iOS, introduced=4.0)
    optional func applicationProtectedDataDidBecomeAvailable(application: UIApplication)

    @availability(iOS, introduced=5.0)
    optional var window: UIWindow? { get set }

    @availability(iOS, introduced=6.0)
    optional func application(application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow window: UIWindow?) -> Int

    // Applications may reject specific types of extensions based on the extension point identifier.
    // Constants representing common extension point identifiers are provided further down.
    // If unimplemented, the default behavior is to allow the extension point identifier.
    @availability(iOS, introduced=8.0)
    optional func application(application: UIApplication, shouldAllowExtensionPointIdentifier extensionPointIdentifier: String) -> Bool

    @availability(iOS, introduced=6.0)
    optional func application(application: UIApplication, viewControllerWithRestorationIdentifierPath identifierComponents: [AnyObject], coder: NSCoder) -> UIViewController?
    @availability(iOS, introduced=6.0)
    optional func application(application: UIApplication, shouldSaveApplicationState coder: NSCoder) -> Bool
    @availability(iOS, introduced=6.0)
    optional func application(application: UIApplication, shouldRestoreApplicationState coder: NSCoder) -> Bool
    @availability(iOS, introduced=6.0)
    optional func application(application: UIApplication, willEncodeRestorableStateWithCoder coder: NSCoder)
    @availability(iOS, introduced=6.0)
    optional func application(application: UIApplication, didDecodeRestorableStateWithCoder coder: NSCoder)

    // Called on the main thread as soon as the user indicates they want to continue an activity in your application. The NSUserActivity object may not be available instantly,
    // so use this as an opportunity to show the user that an activity will be continued shortly.
    // For each application:willContinueUserActivityWithType: invocation, you are guaranteed to get exactly one invocation of application:continueUserActivity: on success,
    // or application:didFailToContinueUserActivityWithType:error: if an error was encountered.
    @availability(iOS, introduced=8.0)
    optional func application(application: UIApplication, willContinueUserActivityWithType userActivityType: String) -> Bool

    // Called on the main thread after the NSUserActivity object is available. Use the data you stored in the NSUserActivity object to re-create what the user was doing.
    // You can create/fetch any restorable objects associated with the user activity, and pass them to the restorationHandler. They will then have the UIResponder restoreUserActivityState: method
    // invoked with the user activity. Invoking the restorationHandler is optional. It may be copied and invoked later, and it will bounce to the main thread to complete its work and call
    // restoreUserActivityState on all objects.
    @availability(iOS, introduced=8.0)
    optional func application(application: UIApplication, continueUserActivity userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: ([AnyObject]!) -> Void) -> Bool

    // If the user activity cannot be fetched after willContinueUserActivityWithType is called, this will be called on the main thread when implemented.
    @availability(iOS, introduced=8.0)
    optional func application(application: UIApplication, didFailToContinueUserActivityWithType userActivityType: String, error: NSError)

    // This is called on the main thread when a user activity managed by UIKit has been updated. You can use this as a last chance to add additional data to the userActivity.
    @availability(iOS, introduced=8.0)
    optional func application(application: UIApplication, didUpdateUserActivity userActivity: NSUserActivity)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. What is the value of having a protocol at all in that case? I can implement some all or none of the functions in the protocol and I can also add functions *not* in the protocol. Is it more like a guide in this case?

Comment: It all depends on your requirement, you can implement those methods or just leave them unimplemented. But your application's delegate still remains your app delegate until unless your change it explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

These methods are optional. The value is that whoever adopts this protocol may implement only selected methods(or none, or all) without leaving empty implementations of not needed methods.

Whoever holds the delegate is now responsible to check if delegate implements certain methods and execute them accordingly.

Think of optional methods in protocol more like an abstraction of public interface. Let's say you have some ClassA with lot's of methods and properties. However you only use method1 and property3 because that's all you need in this case. However for something else you may need method2 and property1, etc.

With delegate pattern you doesn't care who's the delegate. But the delegate needs to know what capabilities it has.